# auto increment in ms access by sql query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I've tried this query in MS Access SQL query section

```
create table demo(
  deomid long not null identity(1,1),
  name varchar(200),

  primary key(userid)
)
```

I also have used `identity , autonumber , autoincrement , autoincrement(1,1) , auto_increment` instead of `identity(1,1)` in the above query.

Every statement produces error saying that syntax error in create table statement...
Please tell what is proper way to auto increment a long field.

Comment: try this: 

deomid not null AUTOINCREMENT,

Comment: you are adding primary column userid that doesnt exist. Try changing the line primary key(userid) to int userid primary key

Comment: @Nanda: Well observed, although I'd think it was the misspelled `demoid` that was meant to be the primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out.

```
CREATE TABLE [demo] ([deomid] AUTOINCREMENT )
```

Answer (score 0):

from here http://www.datanamic.com/support/msaccess-autoinc.html

> Use the COUNTER data type when you want to define an auto
>   increment/auto number/identity column in MS Access. The COUNTER data
>   type provides a monotonically increasing sequence of long integers for
>   a column in a MS Access database.

Answer (score 0):

The `IDENTITY` keyword and any of its synonyms that involve its seed and increment values require [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0).

Also, you can't create a `PRIMARY KEY` on `userid` because it isn't a valid column name. Perhaps you meant to use `deomid`? Try this:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute _
    "create table demo( " & _
    "deomid long not null identity(1,1), " & _
    "name varchar(200), " & _
    "primary key(deomid) " & _
    ")"
```

Note your table still lacks a business key i.e. to be able to identify users in the real world. I would guess there should be a `UNIQUE` constraint on `name` (which should probably not be nullable!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
{
   Emp_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Demo
( 
    [USER_ID] counter PRIMARY KEY, 
    [NAME] varchar(200) null,  
    [NAME_2] varchar(150) not null,  
    [NUMBER] double null,  
    [DATE] datetime not null
)
```